# Восклицательный знак пропускается срезом

Tags: python, python-3.6

Обычный пример

```
>>> text = "this is a test!"
>>> text[:-1:2]
'ti  sats'
```

причем если восклицательный знак убрать, он выведет тоже самое, подскажите что сделать.

Comment: Уберите -1 из среза.

Comment: а какой вывод ожидался о_О?

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `-1` и он выведет то что вы хотите.

Всё дело в том, что вы указываете

```
text[start:end:step]   #начало:конец:шаг
```

В Питоне как во многих других языках программирования индексация идет от `0`.

И указав `-1` вы говорите, что хотите вывести до последнего элемента (**end**), где **end** не входит, и поэтому вышел такой результат.

Answer (score 0):

Один из подходов для понятия работы со срезами состоит в том, что нумеруются *не* элементы, а *промежутки между ними*. Отрицательные значения отсчитывают промежутки с конца строки:

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | t | h | i | s |   | i | s |   | a |   | t | e | s | t | ! |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
-15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

В записи среза

```
строка[нач:кон:шаг]
```

`нач` – *промежуток* начала среза,
`кон` – *промежуток* конца среза,
`шаг` – шаг.

По умолчанию `нач == 0`, `кон == len(строка)`, `шаг == 1`.

Теперь вы сразу видите, что в вашем выражении

```
text[:-1:2]
```

восклицательный знак *не входит в этот срез*, и потому вместо `-1` нужно применить по крайней мере `15` (длину вашей строки `text`), или просто пропустить её, т.к. она по умолчанию ровна `len(text)`:

> ```
> >>> text[::2]
> 'ti sats!'
> ```

или

> ```
> >>> text[:15:2]
> 'ti sats!'
> >>> text[:len(text):2]
> 'ti sats!'
> >>> text[:10000:2]
> 'ti sats!'
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Вы написали

> причем если восклицательный знак убрать, он выведет тоже самое

Теперь вы видите, почему - выражением `text[:-1:2]` вы *исключили последний символ*, в случае строки `"this is a test"` (без символа `!`) исключается символ `t`, *который вы всё-таки пропустили в строке* `"this is a test!"` *шагом* `2`.